# How to conditionally set a dataframe's value based on date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, comparison

I have a pandas dataframe with a few columns of data that I'm passing to MSSQL. My primary key is a file name which changed format as of March 27th, 2014. I'm creating this file name programatically in my dataframe, but I need to account for both versions (one format before and including files created on March 27th, the other for all files after March 27th).

How can I iterate through each row and conditionally set my filename column? I have a datetime column in my dataframe, which has proper datetime format. I just don't know how to do a comparison to the date of change, then create the df[FileName] conditionally.

thanks to @EdChum!

```
dateOfChange = datetime.date(2014, 03, 27)        

df.loc[df['DateTime'] > dateOfChange, 'FileName'] = df.BAC.map(str) + '_' + df.Year.map("{:04}".format, str) + df.Month.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Day.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Hour.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Minute.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Second.map("{:02}".format, str) + "_" + df.NumberDialed.map(str)
df.loc[df['DateTime'] <= dateOfChange, 'FileName'] = df.BAC.map(str) + '_' + df.Year.map("{:04}".format, str) + df.Month.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Day.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Hour.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Minute.map("{:02}".format, str) + df.Second.map("{:02}".format, str)
```

Comment: Do you return any rows for `df.loc[df['DateTime'] <= dateOfChange]`

Comment: typo... (i have FileName and Filename above)

Comment: OK, shall I update my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterating over you can just filter the rows you want to assign to, and assign to all of them. This will be much faster and utilises the power of Pandas:

```
df.loc[df['DateTime'] > dateOfChange, 'FileName'] = someVal
df.loc[df['DateTime'] <= dateOfChange, 'FileName'] = otherVal
```

We use `loc` here to perform label indexing, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label

Comment: its not the date that I'm changing conditionally, but rather whether or not I'm going to append another variable to my FileName series.

Comment: Sorry can you explain better with an example, it is unclear to me

Comment: my FileName will be either ID#_PhoneNumber_Date.flac or ID#_Date.flac depending on when the call was made

Comment: So this should work: `df.loc[df['DateTime'] > dateOfChange, 'FileName'] = ID#_PhoneNumber_Date.flac` for one condition and then `df.loc[df['DateTime'] > dateOfChange, 'FileName'] = ID#_Date.flac` for the other condition

Comment: Please edit all extra info to your question and provide data, expected output and more explanation

Comment: I edited above with real code. unsure why it works for one conditional and not the other...